# Creating a Scalable Label in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I found a post how explains it to create it for Ios.
http://nuvious.com/Blog/2015/5/9/creating-a-scalable-label-in-nativescript

But how to do this in Android.

That is what I tried:

```
import {Label} from "tns-core-modules/ui/label";
function ScalingLabel() {
    this.myLabel = new Label();
    let TextViewCompat;
    if (androidx)
        TextViewCompat = androidx.core.widget.TextViewCompat;
    else
        TextViewCompat = android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat;
    TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(this.myLabel, 8, 100, 1, 2);
}

ScalingLabel.prototype = new Label();
exports.ScalingLabel = ScalingLabel;

Vue.registerElement('ScalingLabel', ScalingLabel);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Could not load view
>   for: nativescalinglabel. Error: Cannot convert object to
>   Landroid/widget/TextView; at index 0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not suppose to create a instance but extend the original class.

```
class ScalingLabel extends Label {
    initNativeView() {
        super.initNativeView();
        if (this.android) {
            androidx.core.widget.TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(this.nativeViewProtected, 10, 100, 1, android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP);
        }
    }
}

Vue.registerElement('ScalingLabel', () => ScalingLabel);
```

Then in your component try,

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout class="form">
                <TextField class="m-15 input input-border" v-model="message">
                </TextField>
                <Label :text="message" class="m-5 h3" />
                <ScalingLabel :text="message" class="m-5 h3" height="30"
                    width="100%" textWrap="true" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                message: ""
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I play around with it. But I noticed when I don't set a height I really don't resize until it's fully seen. https://imgur.com/a/24mhWWR The first one is with a fixed height of 12 the second doesn't have height. The problem is when I have a smaller text with a fixed height of 12 it's hard to see because it can't be bigger.

Comment: Always try to set the height at least 10 points more than font size.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, didn't changed anything.

Comment: The above example works perfectly on my end. If you have issues please share a Playground sample and details of your test device.